# Encapsulate different data sources in an application

Tags: oop, encapsulation, software-design, business-logic

I have the e-commerce website. It is based on Kohana **php**. My business faces new challenges and I'm trying to break my monolithic architecture into small parts.

Right now I have mysql database as the only data-source and access it in my application via ORM or DB queries:

```
$product = ORM::factory('Product', $id_product);
$products = ORM::factory('Product')->where()->find_all()
$products = DB::query(Database::SELECT, "{my complex query}"->as_object('Product')->execute();
```

Problem arises when I decide to move to **other** data source: API, Mongodb, etc. I'm forced to rewrite many lines of my code.

I have gaps in my knowledge of software development and I need some hints, best practises how to encapsulate different data sources in an application.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate your data source interactions using the [adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) and [factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) patterns. Make sure you have mock implementations of the adapters so that you can test interactions in the absence of an actual database.